# File permanently added to form in html

Tags: html

How i can add file to form without input tag? Just open browser and press send. File will be autamaticaly sent.

```
<form Method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" size="20">
       <button onClick = "form.action = 'http://192.168.1.54/restore.cgi'; form.submit ()">
```

I need to input restore_settings.bin to this form
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and add further details please.

Comment: Some information that the OP hasn't mentioned: The task is to send a settings file to a LAN connected device over TCP/IP and the device has a clickable button in the web browser interface to restore the settings file, which prompts for file location.  The settings become corrupted and need to be restored regularly, so  automating this as much as possible is the aim.

Answer (score 0):

You can't due to security reason.  Imagine abuser can get any file that readable to the client from the browser.